# React Redux applyMiddleware invalid number of arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx, middleware

I can't seem to figure this out.  When I use the function applyMiddleware I am unable to pass any arguments in as I get the error invalid number of arguments, expected 0.

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from "redux";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import rootReducer from "./root-reducer";

const middlewares = [logger];
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

export default store;
```

Comment: `createStore` [has](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore) the following API: `createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])`. Try calling it like `createStore(rootReducer, undefined, applyMiddleware(...middlewares))`

Comment: That doesn't work either. I still get the same error.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Invalid number of arguments, expected 0.

Comment: I don't know what could be wrong. Do you have a stack trace with that error? Maybe something in `./root-reducer`

Comment: Are you using an IntelliJ IDE by any chance? I got the same notice from my IDE when writing React code in PHPStorm.

Answer (score 0):

Try using compose to compose your middleWare, should allow you to accept at least 1 argument

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";

const middlewares = [logger];
const composedEnhancers = compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composedEnhancers);
```